# How to get collection from both models in a bi-directional many-to-many relationship in django

Tags: django, many-to-many, bidirectional

I have two objects, Company and Account, in different packages.
They have a many-to-many relation through employee, which has an additional field is_admin.

In Company I define the relation, and reading online, it seems that I don't have to redifine the relation in Account (this will result in a circular import).

Retrieving all the Accounts from the CompanySerializer is no problem,
but I need to be able to get all the Companies registered to an account as well.

This is my thinking:

Account Model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
current_jobs = models.ManyToManyField(
    Company, through='Employee') // I need to define current_jobs in some way
                                 //,but this results in circular import
```

Company Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
employees = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Employee')
```

Employee Model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'company')


user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_admin = models.BooleanField()
```

The problem is, how will I now define how to get each of the lists in the serializers of the two.
So the Company Serializer, and the Account Serializer...

If i do not define current_jobs, I get an error stating that current_jobs is not defined, which it ofcourse is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you think you need to define `current_jobs` on Account. That is automatically provided for you via the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) as `company_set`; if you need it to be `current_jobs` you can set the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) attribute.

Comment: Hehe, I am very new to django, and did not know this was how the variable was named. I am sorry for asking a dumb question! Should have found this out:)! But it did solve my problem, so thank you!